# TypeError and RuntimeError after working fine first run

Tags: python, runtime-error, typeerror, rfid

I am using this Mercury API https://github.com/gotthardp/python-mercuryapi to read RFID tags.

When running the simple example code below, the code produces errors after 1 successful execution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import mercury
reader = mercury.Reader("tmr:///dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=115200)

print(reader.get_model())
print(reader.get_supported_regions())

reader.set_region("EU3")
reader.set_read_plan([1], "GEN2", read_power=1900)
print(reader.read())

reader.start_reading(lambda tag: print(tag.epc, tag.antenna, tag.read_count, tag.rssi))
time.sleep(1)
reader.stop_reading()
```

At the first run the code executes fine producing this reading of the RFID tags.

```
M6e Nano
[u'NA2', u'NA3', u'IN', u'JP', u'PRC', u'EU3', u'KR2', u'AU', u'NZ', u'open']
['E20040057307013122103116']
E20040057307013122103116 1 1 -36
E20040057307013122103116 1 1 -36
E20040057307013122103116 1 1 -36
E20040057307013122103116 1 1 -36
```

Running it again results in this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    reader = mercury.Reader("tmr:///dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=115200)
TypeError: No such file or directory
```

Running again some times results in this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    reader = mercury.Reader("tmr:///dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=115200)
TypeError: Permission denied
```

Running it then from sudo gives and RuntimeError:

```
M6e Nano
[u'NA2', u'NA3', u'IN', u'JP', u'PRC', u'EU3', u'KR2', u'AU', u'NZ', u'open']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(reader.read())
RuntimeError: Timeout
```

Any ideas on how to solve these issues?

*Update* had the reader turned of for some time and the same behaviour happens again. Works the first time then goes into TypeError. Can it be the path "tmr:///dev/ttyUSB0" changing after first use?

*Update* tried running it on a Raspberry Pi 3 and I get the same problem. RuntimeError: Timeout

Comment: Have you added the user running this program to the dialout group?  If that's not the problem, run 'dmesg | grep tty' to make sure your device is attached to ttyUSB0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the RFID reader did not receive enough power. Instead of 3.3V I provided it with 5V which solved the issue.